# execute final mongoose query after loop completes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to run a loop of mongoose queries to update a database based on an array called dateStarts. Then after that, I want to execute a final command, but I want it to use the databases as they *after* all that updating. As written, the final query seems to be running before the loop is done. How do I fix that?

```
dateStarts.forEach(function(datevalue)
        {
            var conditions = {//conditions};
            var update     = {//updates};
            titleRecords.update(conditions, update, options, function(err, data)
            {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }) //end of forEach loop
        titleRecords.remove({//finalcondition});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `update` is an asynchronous operation, that is why `remove` is execute before of the updates. You can build an array of promises and use `Promise.all` to resolve all of the updates before doing that remove:

```
var updatePromises = dateStarts.map((datevalue) => {
    var conditions = {//conditions};
    var update     = {//updates};
    return titleRecords.update(conditions, update, options);
});

Promise.all(updatePromises)
  .then(() => titleRecords.remove({//finalcondition}))
  .catch((error) => ...);
```

To make mongoose use the native promise (node version 6 or higher), you can do this at the top:

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```